# Why can the Grid and Column APIs be undefined or null during the gridReady event?

Tags: typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm currently upgrading ag-Grid from v18 to v19.

One thing that I noticed is that on the `gridReady` event it guarantees that the Grid and Column APIs are available. This makes sense to me since once the ag-Grid finishes its initialization, it can provide the APIs for use.

When I upgraded, the typing changed so that during the `gridReady` event, these APIs may be absent.

Version 18:

```
interface AgGridEvent extends AgEvent {
    api: GridApi;
    columnApi: ColumnApi;
}
```

Version 19:

```
interface AgGridEvent extends AgEvent {
    api: GridApi | null | undefined;
    columnApi: ColumnApi | null | undefined;
}
```

What does it mean that these APIs can be absent during this event? What situation can occur that will not provide these APIs on `gridReady`?

Thanks.

Comment: I also noticed the same pattern in other ag-Grid events that supposedly happen only after it has initialized. It doesn't make sense to me that these APIs can be absent.

Comment: Please provide some example of using ag-grid. I'm using ag-grid v19. And everything works fine. Maybe you do something wrong.

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: @RomanSkydan
This isn't a problem that I can reproduce in code since it's an issue with the typing. I've added the change in types to make it more explicit.

Comment: @ChrisDuncan Looks like it has been changed back in v20: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/commit/d31f5ab230fb8141f3493e67abd09cc6f1da2e80